# Setting up Review Apps in Spinnaker

Tags: github, spinnaker

I was wondering if there is any way to configure review apps in Spinnaker like [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps) or [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/) have? Looked through documentation and forums and couldn't find anything. Just verifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger spinnaker pipeline using merge request event from GitLaband deploy your app under review to separeate namespace.

The main task is to implement correct lifecycle and clear obsolate applications using Spinnaker pipelines. But it is possible with current Spinnaker's functionality.